# How can we use local computer database of SQL Server 2012 as a REST API for mobile app?

Tags: android, sql, asp.net

I Have some critical Database on SQL Server 2012 , but now i have android app , where i want to access/search /query this database  that already created on my local computer. there is no issue of Public IP.

How can we use local computer database of SQL Server 2012 as a REST API for mobile app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a web API with ASP.NET on your pc's `IIS` and publish it on `inetpub` and use sql-server data in it(can be local or remote).
Here is an tutorial for this:

[create a web API with ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Good luck

Comment: My point is that this is one of many possible approaches. It is not something the OP "must" do. And the question itself, as written, is very broad, with no work and just a set of requirements.